# Raspberry Pi 3B+ PoE Amplifier Suggestion

Tags: raspberry-pi, amplifiers, poe

I have been looking around and haven't been able to find an answer to this so hoping you guys can help.

I have been tasked with finding a way to power a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (using the PoE Hat) as well as an Adafruit Amplifier remotely using only PoE power.

Initially the thought came to me to use a PoE splitter but I was concerned about the split of power and if PoE would continue through to the RPi to power it or if it was only Data passthrough.

My next thought was to use the 5V GPIO Pins on the RPi to power it but, I quickly realized that it wouldn't be enough power to get the speakers loud enough for the application.

If anyone has had similar problems/solutions any assistance would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Not that this question is necessarily off topic, but I would strongly recommend raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or electronics.stackexchange.com instead. I agree that running it off the GPIO probably isn't a great idea, but is there anything wrong with splicing the 5V DC input that's going into the Pi? Depending on how much power you're drawing on the Pi (read: how much compute you need to do/is it okay to throttle), the 2.5A limit of the hat might be an issue, but you could always ditch the hat for a more powerful power supply.

Comment: That was my initial plan, but the problem came later not when at low volume with the amplifier but at the levels that I needed it at, would pull almost 3A and that alone would slaughter the RPi so I needed another method. And we are trying to use PoE in the system to avoid having to bring in electricians to install additional outlets. (my apologies for having it in the wrong location, will go to one of the suggested spots for the next RPi question thank you)

Comment: Oh I just meant using another PoE based 5V PSU. Seems you've got it working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many hours of testing different methods to go for maximum volume (which was required) we ended up running 2 PoE lines and used a PoE splitter because it was significantly cheaper then running a power line (involves hiring an electrician and can get expensive. Very quick).